# What will be the problem of adding .net framework class library reference in .net core project?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

Could anyone help me to understand what will be the drawback of doing so. I can understand that we will loose platform Independence by doing so but is there any other problem.?

Any suggestions or thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this article can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/april/net-core-net-goes-cross-platform-with-net-core

Comment: Yes there are and they depend on the actual library. It may or may not have a completely incompatible dependency for example. It may or may not read settings directly from web.config (which no longer exists). If you try to use a WCF proxy for example, it will try to read the default settings from web.config. You should reverse the question. Which library are you trying to reference, why not use a .NET Core or .NET Standard library, or why not *rebuild* the library as a .NET Standard one?

Comment: I was just trying to understand what will be the drawback.  I thought of compatibility and platform support issues. question is why such provision is given because if we do so we end up into .net framework app instead of .net core.

Answer (score 1):

I think your use case, is a much of an importance as the question itself. Why would you want to add .net framework class library instead of a .net core one? or even better a .net standard? e.g. are you ever planning on running your application on a linux server? then i would say, stick to .net core (or standard).

A definition I found on the microsoft doc states:

> Class libraries are the shared library concept for .NET. They enable
>   you to componentize useful functionality into modules that can be used
>   by multiple applications. They can also be used as a means of loading
>   functionality that is not needed or not known at application startup.
>   Class libraries are described using the .NET Assembly file format.

([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/class-libraries][1])

They further define there libraries into 3 categories:

1. Platform-specific class libraries
2. Portable class libraries
3. .NETStandard class libraries

So I guess that this expands your question even further are you bound to use you class library in a different application, if so, does it run on the same platform? if not? which type of library would support both platforms?

So to answer your question. If you are planning to run on host your application on windows I dont see much of a problem of adding a reference to the .net framework class library. If you are writing the library yourself, think about what the possible usages of the library are in the future and on which other platform (mobile and non mobile) it needs to be able to be hosted.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I was just trying to understand what will be the drawback.  I thought of compatibility and platform support issues. question is why such provision is given because if we do so we end up into .net framework app instead of .net core.

Comment: That is exactly correct, compatibility and plaftorm support are the biggest drawbacks. But the read question lies in why you want to introduce the .net framework library? is it a third party library? because otherwise you can just stick to .net core or .net standard.

Comment: one of my client wats DB first EF approach which is not available with EFCore hence they are adding .net framework reference in .net core project

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check this out:
https://www.ben-morris.com/sharing-libraries-between-net-core-and-net-framework-applications/

If the framework requirements are met you "should" be OK however a year or two down the road...